# where do I put jquery to trigger an on click event in rails?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I downloaded a datepicker plugin that is done in jquery. The format is as follows:

```
$('#date-picker').datepicker('show')
```

when I run this command from the console, everything works.

However, I'm not sure where to put this so that when the page loads and someone clicks the text box, the date picker appears. I tried putting it in application.js but no luck. what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to put it inside of `$(document).ready`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#date-picker').datepicker('show');
});
```

edit:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('your-input-box-selector').click(function() {
    $('#date-picker').datepicker('show');
  });
});
```

Comment: great, that worked. how do I make it appear only when someone clicks within the input box?

Comment: See edit. Replace 'your-input-box-selector' with a selector to your particular input box (by id, class, or otherwise).

Comment: @MatthewBerman you read a book/post, or ask another question.  Selectors are a fundamental aspect of the question domain :/

Answer (score 0):

Well i suggest you to use `.class` instead of `#id` notation because id notations should be unique and you have to add the id everytime if you want it to be a `datepicker`, if you do it with class names then that will be much easier to maintain and you don't need to do any more work in js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.date-picker').datepicker('show');
});
```